# "Capped collections" in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, capped-collections

[Cassandra doesn't have capped collections (or row size limits)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3929), but one way of simulating it is to use an offline mapreduce job clean up extra entries. Would it be better to have a second table that stores row counts for primary keys in another table? The downside is that you have to scan through the entire row_count table since counters aren't indexable. Or would it be faster to just scan over the backing table with the real data?

Or is there another technique I should look into?

Edit: I found this [Columns count vs counter column performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272115/columns-count-vs-counter-column-performance). Row counts go over all the data, so I'm leaning away from that.